# How to use NgRx MockStore setState?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, state, ngrx-store

When I am in a unit test with a MockStore, and I use setState on the MockStore, it does not seem to work on its own. See the following code. This code works. But it wouldn't without first calling `store.setState({});`. This feels hacky. Why is that required, or what am I doing wrong?

```
function setSelectedBook(bookId: string) {
  let state = (store.source as BehaviorSubject<IAppState>).value;
  state = {
    ...state,
  };
  state.library.bookIdSelected = bookId;
  store.setState({});
  store.setState(state);
}
```

`store` is defined as `let store: MockStore;` and provided to the TestBed just like in [the docs](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/testing#using-a-mock-store) `provideMockStore({ initialState })`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're directly mutating the `state.library` object and without the prior `store.setState({})`, you'd send the **same reference** of `state.library`, which can lead to some unexpected results.

For example, if you have selectors created with `createSelector` and the `library` is part of the **projection function**'s arguments, you'll get the previously computed result, because the `prevArguments.library` object has the same reference as `currentArguments.library`.

`setState({})` is like a **deeper refresh**, as you're sending a completely new reference.

`setState(state)` is a different reference compared to `{}`, so every selector's projection function should be re-run.

I think it should work fine without `setState({})` if you do:

```js
state = {
  ...state,
  library: {
    ...state.library,
    bookIdSelected: bookId,
  }
};

store.setState(state);
```

Comment: Yes! That was it. I thought it would be enough to do `state = {...state,`. But, as you pointed out, this is also needed at sub-levels of the data tree, if data in it changed. Thanks.